# How can I conditionally include methods on a class based on a type parameter?

Tags: typescript

I can use conditional types to conditionally include methods on an interface:

```
interface Iter<T> {
  flatten: T extends Iterable<infer A> ? () => Set<A> : never;
}
```

Is there a way of doing this with a class as well?

Comment: you can replace `interface` with `class` and it should work exactly the same. Is that the question?

Comment: @TobiasS. That gives the error `Property 'flatten' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor`. I think I'm missing the part on how to actually add the method in a way that conforms with the conditional type.

Comment: OK so I've gotten this far but it would be nice to get rid of the `as any`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSAuBTATgHgCoD5oG8BQ00wA9gHYTzICuw8xyAFAJS4GHTwAWAlhAHQAzcPCSloAXmgNmE7KUQB3aAGVE8Zi0jQwpAJ4BuNgF82QsCMSkAXNHTREAD1EATGAhRgARiESpupARRoAEFsAH4pFnFsVXhUUOgbeQA3FEMTPBJyeGgzC1IvHwloeSV3NABtUioAW08UABoS2vrkAF1MZkM80ULEQWFRLsyyCmgqAMHLPuLSuCQ0arqUTqZDCZ7p737N0i6gA

Comment: You can remove `any` by spelling out the whole conditional for the assertion: https://tsplay.dev/mx8G7m. But there is not gonna be any type checking either way.

Comment: Ah yes of course, thank you. But as you say, the use of `as` can be somewhat unsafe. I wonder if there's a way that avoids `as` altogether.

Comment: I would say there is no way to avoid some kind of type assertion. TypeScript generally can't correlate conditional types (especially with generic types) to your implementation.

Comment: @AlexChashin I'm not seeing how that would help - ultimately I want Iter to be a class so it seems I would still have the same problem.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem to me; presumably, something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrXLzW) would be more appropriate, where the class always has a `flatten()` method (unless you really want to make it an instance property) but you can only call it if `T` is iterable.  This avoids type assertions as well as conditional types, and only uses `this` parameters and generics.  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) for a "standard" level of safety, or at least [the `--strictPropertyInitialization` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#--strictpropertyinitialization), then you need to initialize any class member you have.

But it's essentially impossible for the compiler to verify that a value is assignable to a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter; it just *defers* evaluation of the type until such time as the generic type parameter is specified.  Something like `T extends Iterable<infer A> ? () => Set<A> : never;` is therefore opaque to the compiler, and so there's not really anything you can assign to `flatten` without using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to quell the compiler's concerns about type safety.

So you *could* do something like this:

```
class Iter<T> {
  constructor(public prop: T) { }
  flatten = (function (this: Iter<T>) {
    return new Set(this.prop as Iterable<any>)
  } as T extends Iterable<infer A> ? () => Set<A> : never;
}
```

which works:

```
const a = new Iter(123);
try {
  const oops = a.flatten(); // error! 
  // ----------> ~~~~~~~
  // never has no call signatures
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // this.prop is not iterable
}

const b = new Iter([1, 2, 3]);
const okay = b.flatten();
// const okay: Set<number>
```

but it's clunky and weird, even aside from the type assertion. You don't really want `flatten` to be an instance property, do you?  It's more like a method that lives on the class prototype.  And you're lying to the compiler because when `T` is not iterable, then you claim that `flatten` is of type `never` which is impossible.

---

Instead, I'd think what you actually want is for `flatten` to be a method that always exists, but is only safe to call when `T` is iterable.  You can get that effect with a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters):

```
class Iter<T> {
  constructor(public prop: T) { }
  flatten<A>(this: Iter<Iterable<A>>) {
    return new Set(this.prop)
  }
}
```

That compiles without type assertions or conditional types, and is verified as safe by the compiler.  The return type of `flatten` is `Set<A>`, when called on an `Iter<T>` which is assignable to `Iter<Iterable<A>>`.

This behaves similarly from the caller's side, and the error is more descriptive of the issue (it isn't that `flatten` is `never`, but that `a` is not an `Iter<Iterable<A>>`):

```
const a = new Iter(123);
try {
  const oops = a.flatten(); // error! 
  // --------> ~
  // The 'this' context of type 'Iter<number>' is not assignable 
  // to method's 'this' of type 'Iter<Iterable<unknown>>'.
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // this.prop is not iterable
}

const b = new Iter([1, 2, 3]);
const okay = b.flatten();
// const okay: Set<number>
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLIDCA9sACYCWALo3ZnkUSSfBiFChIAkswgAnADwAVAHydiPXnSjNxAV3jMa4gBQx1AIwyN4SGOJowAXEmkBKPEgC+3JUgBm-ZmOBIAvEi6HurAWmx+uswAFoxQtqISMrKOBIruSOIQzOrifsAQAO5IAMrZUbFQAHQWVkgCImLiIMYQkiDAAJ4pbkrO9ULSSBAAHr70QonNrZKMwB4SSACC8gD8QY7+8mXMkitItgUAbhIA3L0uF-AqzPUBpEWNEroAjABMAMz25+lIap0KDLXYCqJA0KxCQIgKpeEA+CDAXTfJAAehRw3ElnEAEIkBcSGikABaEmksnyAB+VOpFPxqPRx0W0QawBoSHQGAwSCgjAA5qAclkoBd+uhmPBokEIKk6cCoDQMBAqhgaLzdNLTvS-pUapYYEg4qQaLcWBIWoqRVxfnLboZ7gVilNdABtF4AGiQbw9HwAut8rjcwQBrEAAwKGGHeXxIn5KQk24Oh2w7STAdRgQwSWRWtyuRRkaBwRBIADiCIkpmklQACiBmmBATw+AJJk1ko2lLD4cA9rIKnEEm2pua2isUh33FlBflHjt+9VajB7HS80CbhotDp9EYTGZF7YHAoV5bCAGQbcQPbHk73l9Yzx-hPlOewRD7tCu9HkYSJFjcXTCTJckkFpX4CXRKtkAAchiOIoPZOgxDGMEPD+ToYGgqZU3TTNxFkeDDVZC9BD5UBWjxMCtW0JBIBiGh6CgoQYMqeCaFQ5h0MwocmhHSRQiDVlCmAWR8KqEV2ThCUpRlSi5QVJUVTVDUqJ1RcDSEIiDR41oTzPUE7UCB0nj0V0PS9JBfX9a1AxoEMwyQCNPwRGMLnjGy7OTbJsIzLMrRIPMiGcIA)